# how to use command line to find what version of Notepad++ is installed

Tags: command-line

I'm trying to write a shell script that lists versions of specific packages that are installed.  However, this command does not display what version of Notepad++ is installed:
`notepad-plus-plus --version`
What is the correct command to find this info?

Comment: That is program specific and chosen by the programmer/developer.  If you know the programmer's background you could guess how he/she would likely provide clues (eg. '--help' if GNU background for help, '-h' or '-?' for BSD etc...)  That's how I'd look for it; '--version' implies GNU background, '-v' for .... '-V'...   We far from the early 1970s so there are many many standards developers can choose from.

Comment: `snap list | awk '/notepad-plus-plus/ {print $2}'`

Comment: `notepad-plus-plus` is _not_ a package and not even a file installable from [Ubuntu packages](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=notepad-plus-plus). How did you get it?

Comment: @Melebius A snap installation of a Windows application...